# Inner products on differential forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given a Riemannian metric $g$ on a smooth manifold $M$, one defines an
$L^2$-inner product on the space $\bigwedge^\ast(M)$ of differential
forms by

$$
  \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle_g = \int_M \alpha \wedge \ast_g \beta,
$$

where $\ast_g$ denotes the Hodge-star operator relative to $g$, and
$\alpha, \beta$ are forms of the same degree.

**Question**: Does every inner product on $\bigwedge^\ast(M)$ as a graded
vector space come from some metric $g$? How about inner products on
$k$-forms $\bigwedge^k(M)$ for a single $k$, especially $0 < k < \dim
M$?

Comment: Restrict your inner product on $\wedge^\ast (M)$ to functions... is it a metric?

Comment: @David: It is the usual $L^2$ metric induced by $g$: since $*1 = \operatorname{vol}_g$, $\langle h, k \rangle_g = \int_M h k \, d\operatorname{vol}_g$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $L^2$ inner product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixing a $k$ for simplicity, there are many inner products on $\bigwedge^k (M)$ (which I would usually denote $\Omega^k (M)$).  Since $\bigwedge^k T^* M$ is a vector bundle, there are, for example, Sobolev $H^s$ inner products on its space of smooth sections for any natural number $s$.  See, for example, Palais, *Foundations of Global Non-Linear Analysis*.

Comment: Just to expand on your answer a little (for my own benefit?): If I understand the question asked, it is whether every inner product on $\Omega^k(M)$ is the $L^2$ inner product for some Riemannian metric on $M$. Since (for closed manifolds) the  Sobolev $H^s$ norm  for a fixed $s$ but two different Riemannian metrics are equivalent, but for different $s$ are inequivalent, then e.g. the $H^1$ inner product on $\Omega^k(M)$ can never be the $L^2=H^0$ inner product for any riemannian metric on $M$.

Comment: Thanks, Brian and Paul - that's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks also to José for an entirely different (at least for me) point of view.

Answer (score 4):

One can think of differential forms on a smooth manifold $M$ as spinors of the Clifford bundle constructed out of the vector bundle $TM \oplus T^*M$ with the split signature inner product induced from the dual pairing.

This identification does not respect the grading, though, only the parity (i.e., the reduction mod 2 of the usual grading).

Spinor modules have invariant inner products and in particular those of split signature Clifford algebras $Cl(n,n)$ have inner products which are either symmetric with split signature or symplectic.

This is explained in Chapter 12 (especially table 12.30) in Harvey's *Spinors and calibrations* and also in [Marco Gualtieri's thesis](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401221), where this inner product on forms  goes by the name of the Mukai pairing.

It does not require a metric on $M$ for it to be defined, so the answer to your question seems to be "No", at least if by "inner product" you allow any non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form.